# Where can I farm lives in Mega Man 1?

Tags: mega-man

Is there a good stage to farm extra lives in the original Mega Man for NES? I keep making it to the boss checkpoints before running out of lives and having to replay the stage.

Comment: depending on your version, you could try and see if this bug works for you... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2VsljQOk6k